# TeXworks viewer shows no video

Tags: pdftex, texworks, media9

I ran the code below in pdfLaTeX editor supplied by TeXworks. It produced a PDF in which the requested video played as desired, However, the **viewer** that TeXworks provides showed no video, but only the 'video should appear' text and the poster text. Moreover, the cursor appeared as a magnifying glass, which indeed caused the poster text to get bigger when clicked. Is this a bug in the TeXworks pdfLaTeX viewer? If the viewer is simply not intended to have this capability, this should be clearly stated in its documentation somewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9} 
\begin{document}
The video should appear just below.

 \includemedia[
    width=0.4\linewidth,
    height=0.3\linewidth,
    label='firsttry',
    addresource=40631H264.mp4,
    activate=pageopen,
   flashvars={source=40631H264.mp4}
  ]{This is the poster text}{VPlayer.swf}

The video should appear just above.
\end{document}
```

Comment: most pdf viewers will not show the video, I think. `texdoc media9` lists some viewers that do and do not work.

Comment: Currently, only two readers work: A-Reader for Win and A-Reader for OSX. Not texworks, not evince, not the embedded PDF viewers of popular web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the `media9` package (section Requirements):

> Adobe Reader, version ≥ 9, but not greater than 9.4.1 on Linux; Foxit Reader (Flash, video, audio)

For TeXworks you can say that this editor is more intended to be an editor rather than a full-featured "all-PDF-features-viewer".

*Update:* With some luck, you'll find Okular (on Linux) opening some media types too.